# Remove/hide the separator in DataRepeater control in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, datarepeater

I have a DataRepeater Control in Windows Forms application. The items are separated by a horizontal line, which I want to hide or remove if possible. Can anyone suggest how to do this? Thanks.